# How to format output from a python file using shell_exec()

Tags: python, php, formatting, backend, web-development-server

I currently have php code that outputs data from a python file. This is the output that is successfully ran.

```
Total = 11 Number of Correct Answers = 4 Percentage Correct = 36.36363636363637 % Number of Incorrect Answers = 7 Percentage Wrong = 63.63636363636363 % [['0' '1' '2'] ['0' '3' '13'] ['0' '4' '14'] ['0' '2' '8'] ['1' '2' '6'] ['0' '4' '18'] ['1' '1' '2'] ['0' '2' '7'] ['0' '3' '14'] ['0' '2' '7'] ['0' '1' '2']] [1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0] probabilities [[0.47642793 0.52357207] [0.94137447 0.05862553] [0.95579032 0.04420968] [0.81265167 0.18734833] [0.7674815 0.2325185 ] [0.98345533 0.01654467] [0.53448523 0.46551477] [0.77109059 0.22890941] [0.95386825 0.04613175] [0.77109059 0.22890941] [0.47642793 0.52357207]]
```

I do not know how to format this output back on my php page. Obviously, when you run the py file in terminal, it formats perfectly. I want to have proper line breaks. Something like

```
Total = 11
Number of Correct Answers

Percentage Correct.
```

I have tried to implement line breaks into the actual py file but when the php file outputs the data from the py file it always comes out in the scenario above.

Here is my code:

php-

```
<?php
                
              $email = $_SESSION['email'];
                
              
              $command = escapeshellcmd("C:/Python38/python.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/Ensemble/login/test.py $email"); 
              $output = shell_exec("$command 2>&1");
              print($output);
             
              
            ?>
```

py:

```
print("Total =", len(training_set)) 

print("Number of Correct Answers =", len(correct))
print("Percentage Correct =", 1.*len(correct)/len(training_set)*100.0, "%")
 
print("Number of Incorrect Answers =", len(incorrect))
print("Percentage Wrong =", 1.*len(incorrect)/len(training_set)*100.0, "%")
```

(There are more outputs with the matrices but I am trying to focus on these py elements first).

Comment: if you display it in HTML then you have to put `<br>` in place of `\n` - because HTML doesn't care of `\n` (new line) - and you can do it in PHP with [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php). Or you would have to display it in `<code> your text </code>` to display `\n` as new line.

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't care of \n (new line) and you have to use `<br>` to move to next line.

You can add it in Python in every `print()`

```
print("Total =", len(training_set), '<br>')
```

Or you can replace in PHP using [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

```
print( nl2br($output) );
```

---

Eventually you can display text in `<code></code>` or `<pre></pre>`

```
<pre>

<?php
    print( $output );
?>

</pre>
```

and it will respect `\n` but I don't remeber if you can use other HTML tags inside to format it.

It will also use monospace font like in terminal.